# CanvasJS and millisecond time X Axis

Tags: javascript, safari, canvasjs

I have created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jymxu523/4/

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
  title:{
    text: "Converting in Local Time"
  },

  axisX:{
    title: "time",
    gridThickness: 2,
    interval:1, 
    // hangs on safari at least if I try uncomment this
    //intervalType: "millisecond",        
    valueFormatString: "HH:mm fff ", 
    labelAngle: -20
  },
  axisY:{
    title: "distance"
  },
  data: [
  {        
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: [//array timestamps with millis
    {x: new Date(Date.UTC (2015, 05, 13, 11, 40, 26, 594730) ), y: 26 },
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC (2015, 05, 13, 11, 40, 26, 798973) ), y: 38  },
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2015, 05, 13, 11, 40, 27, 004165) ), y: 43 },
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2015, 05, 13, 11, 40, 27, 209837) ), y: 29},
    {x: new Date( Date.UTC(2015, 05, 13, 11, 40, 27, 417610) ), y: 41}
    ]
  }
  ]
});

chart.render();
```

And it seems I cannot get canvasJS to plot at millisecond accuracy. I have plot data that I want the hours, minute, second and millisecond on. But no matter how I try format the X axis, the plotting gets all messed up.

Comment: When I try set the intervalType to 'millisecond' and the valueFormatString to 'fff' I get a browser hang in Chrome and Safari. Am I doing something horribly wrong or is this a bug in canvasJS?

Answer (score 0):

I was using microseconds, instead of millis. So it was just a case of using 1/1000th instead of 1/1000000th for the 6th argument.

```
{x: new Date(Date.UTC (2015, 05, 13, 11, 40, 26, 594) ), y: 26 },
```